# Inner Join com duas chaves com python

Tags: python, join, pandas, inner

Tenho duas tabelas uma de consulta e outra de exames, nas duas tem a data de execução e o código do beneficiário. Quer fazer uma terceira tabela com as pessoas que fizeram exames e consultas na mesma data.

Se for em SQL faria assim:

```
 Select t1.cod_benf,
        t1.data_execucao,
        t1.cod_serviço,
        t1.valor_pago,
        t2.cod_serviço,
        t2.valor_pago
From base_consulta as t1 inner join base_exame as t2
      on (t1.cod_benf = t2.cod_benf 
      and t1.data_execucao = t2.data_execucao);
```

Como faço isso em python?

BASES:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E você não pode simplesmente executar essa instrução como uma string?

Comment: Por mais que a sua pergunta seja aparentemente simples de resolver, você deveria prover o máximo de informações possíveis para que a comunidade consiga reproduzir seu problema e validar os testes. Disponibilize uma amostra de dados de entrada(pode ser o resultado do `df.head()` de ambos os DFs) e como deve ser a saída dos dados com base nessa amostra

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem da base.

Comment: Se colocar alguns dados ou arquivos de dados que quem for responder possa copiar e colar para resolver o problema também facilita. 
COmo está a pergunta obriga, além de tudo, quem for responder a criar um conjunto de dados para poder prover uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando os dados que você forneceu e python3:

1) Construindo as tabelas:

```
#Constrói os dicionários com os dados fornecidos para as bases:

consulta = {'cod_benefic' : ['123456','635241','968574'],
'cod_servico' : ['101010','101010','101010'],
'dat_execucao' : ['02/01/2016','03/01/2016','04/01/2016'],
'valor' : [65,65,65]}

exame = {'cod_benefic' : ['123456','123456','635241','635241','968574'],
'cod_servico' : ['401231','401250','401261','401250','401261'],
'dat_execucao' : ['02/01/2016','02/01/2016','03/01/2016','03/01/2016','04/01/2016'],
'valor' : [18,10,5,10,5]}
```

```
#import o pacote pandas
import pandas as pd

# transforma o dicionario em pandas dataframe
base_consulta = pd.DataFrame(data=consulta)
base_exame = pd.DataFrame(data=exame)

#transforma a data do tipo string para datetime
base_consulta['dat_execucao'] = pd.to_datetime(base_consulta['dat_execucao'])
base_exame['dat_execucao'] = pd.to_datetime(base_exame['dat_execucao'])

# pode usar df.dtypes para verificar os tipos das variaveis do seu df(dataframe)
# df.head() para mostrar algumas linhas do seu df
```

```
#base_consulta
    cod_benefic cod_servico dat_execucao  valor
0      123456      101010   2016-02-01     65
1      635241      101010   2016-03-01     65
2      968574      101010   2016-04-01     65
```

```
#base_exame
  cod_benefic cod_servico dat_execucao  valor
0      123456      401231   2016-02-01     18
1      123456      401250   2016-02-01     10
2      635241      401261   2016-03-01      5
3      635241      401250   2016-03-01     10
4      968574      401261   2016-04-01      5
```

2) Após a criação das tabelas vamos ao que interessa: fazer o join das tabelas.

- Para fazer os join das tabelas vamos usar o pacote pandas.

```
#Faz o join das tabelas
df3 = pd.merge(base_consulta,base_exame,how='inner', on=['cod_benefic','dat_execucao'],suffixes=('_t1', '_t2'))

#Mostra as primeiras linhas
df3.head()

  cod_benefic cod_servico_t1 dat_execucao  valor_t1 cod_servico_t2  valor_t2
0      123456         101010   2016-02-01        65         401231        18
1      123456         101010   2016-02-01        65         401250        10
2      635241         101010   2016-03-01        65         401261         5
3      635241         101010   2016-03-01        65         401250        10
4      968574         101010   2016-04-01        65         401261         5
```

Para mais informações da uma olhada na documentação do pandas.([Link documentacao Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html))

Answer (score 0):

Tendo as tabelas em dataframes do Pandas, basta usar  a sintaxe de índice do Python - o `[ ]`, colocando dentro dos colchetes uma expressão booleana que pode usar uma ou mais colunas de qualquer dataframe (nesse ponto elas são vistas como 'séries'), desde que o index das séries seja o mesmo (isso é, a coluna especial que funciona como index - pode ser uma numeração sequencial, mas nesse caso poderia ser o próprio código "cod_benefic". ). Os valores no dataframe inicial para os quais a expressão utilizada são verdadeiros são selecionados.

Primeiro um exemplo mais simples - um dataframe com uma coluna cujos valores são simplesmente uma sequência numérica - uso a sintaxe de índice para selecionar as linhas cujos números sejam divisíveis por 3 (isso é o resto da divisão por 3 - % 3- é igual a 0):

```
In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame({"numeros":range(0,20)},)                                                                  

In [24]: df[df["numeros"] % 3 == 0]                                                                                   
Out[24]: 
    numeros
0         0
3         3
6         6
9         9
12       12
15       15
18       18
```

Entendido o mecanismo de seleção, vamos criar dois dataframes com duas colunas com valores que em um dataframe sejam um subconjunto de outo e  realizar um join. (Note que neste exemplo, temos os mesmos códigos de beneficiarios, e datas que são iguais em apenas 50% dos casos entre as tabelas distintas)

Dados dois dataframes:

```
In [73]: df1                                                                                                          
Out[73]: 
   cod_benef       datas  codigo_1
0        272  2019-04-23       100
1        141  2019-04-12       101
2        104  2019-04-28       102
3        203  2019-04-14       103
4        143  2019-04-29       104
5        112  2019-04-29       105
6        259  2019-04-19       106
7        281  2019-04-17       107
8        180  2019-04-24       108
9        175  2019-04-22       109

In [74]: df2                                                                                                          
Out[74]: 
   cod_benef       datas  codigo_2
0        272  2019-05-01       200
1        141  2019-04-19       201
2        104  2019-04-28       202
3        203  2019-05-01       203
4        143  2019-04-16       204
5        112  2019-04-29       205
6        259  2019-04-23       206
7        281  2019-04-17       207
8        180  2019-04-23       208
9        175  2019-04-22       209
```

Especificamos a condição de join como uma série resultante de operações de comparação e outras entre as colunas dos dois frames. Deve se usar os operadores `&` para `and` e `|` para `or`, e pares de parenteses extras, já que a 
precedencia desses operadores é maior que a dos comparadores `==`.

Essa mesma condição deve ser usada em ambos os dataframes de onde vamos pegar valores, então é melhor guarda-la numa variável separada:

```
In [75]: join_cond = (df1["cod_benef"] == df2["cod_benef"]) & (df1["datas"] == df2["datas"])
```

E em seguida, basta montar o dataframe com os resultados desejados com `pandas.concat`, usando a série de condições acima para selecionar as linhas de cada DataFrame de entrada, e o operador de índice,depois de feita a seleção das linhas, para selecionar as colunas desejadas de cada DataFrame no resultado final:

```
In [76]: df3 = pd.concat((df1[join_cond], df2[join_cond][["codigo_2"]] ), axis=1)
```

E voilá:

```
Out[77]: 
   cod_benef       datas  codigo_1  codigo_2
2        104  2019-04-28       102       202
5        112  2019-04-29       105       205
7        281  2019-04-17       107       207
9        175  2019-04-22       109       209
```

Apenas note que isso não é "O Python", e sim, a forma de fazer isso com Pandas. Se os dados estivessem no Python em outra estrutura de dados, a forma de seleção seria diferente- o Pandas por sua natureza acaba exisgindo uma forma própria de se pensar e resolver os problemas do que acontece em Python puro.

Comment: Acho válido ressaltar que essa solução só funcionará se os 2 DataFrames possuírem o mesmo número de linhas.